# Out of range exception thrown when declaring a C++ vector on the free store

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, new-operator, outofrangeexception

I'm working on a problem from Stroustrup's PPP book, Chapter 17 - the Drill.
I keep getting out of range errors thrown and believe I may be accessing the vector m_vec incorrectly when I am initializing its values.  I have tried both '*' and '&' operators with the vector declared [[with size = 10]] but get errors like C6200 Index '4' is out of  range '0' to '1' for non-stack buffer 'm_vec'.

Here is my code - can anyone help out please --

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_array10(std::ostream &os, int *a, int n);
void print_vector(std::ostream &os, std::vector<int> vec1);

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::vector;

    //create the ostream for printing
    std::ostream os(std::cout.rdbuf());

    // allocate a vector of int on the free store and initialize it

    vector<int>* m_vec = new vector<int>( 10 );
                    // vector<Type> *vect = new vector<Type>(integer); allocates the vector size
                    // with everything on the free store (except vect pointer, which is on the stack).


    // initialize the vector with integers starting at 100
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
        m_vec->push_back(1);
        m_vec[i] = { i };
    };

    cout << &m_vec[4] << endl;
    cout << "  " << m_vec->size() << endl;



    //print_vector(os, *m_vec);

    delete m_vec;
    return 0;
};


// create print_vector function
void print_vector(std::ostream &os, std::vector<int> vec1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << vec1[i] << std::endl;
};
```

I got the array portion of this Drill working and was able to access the array (on the free store) with either the pointer // dereference // or [] subscript operators.  When I try the same approach on this vector declared on the free store I get "out of  range" exceptions at runtime.

What is the "non-stack" buffer associated with the vector I created on the free store?  How can I fix this?

I also get some occasional error message advising that I'm using a 32 bit integer in a 16 bit space... which I don't really understand given the code above.  It occurs when I add 100 to 'i' in the for loop to initialize the vector. Any ideas on this... I thought integers were all 32 bits.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You misunderstood the exercise slightly. When using a vector, you don't have to use `new`, it does that for you. So just `vector<int> vec(10);` will get you a vector, and **it** allocates space on the heap to store that values. You don't have to - and that was Stroustrup's point (which he could have been more explicit about).

Comment: Perhaps, and I considered that after rereading the Chapter, but, at page 607 Stroustrup states "Creating the vector on the free store, the 'new' operator -- First allocates memory for the vector. -- Then invokes the vector's constructor to initialize that vector; the constructor allocates memory for the vector's elements and initializes those elements."

Comment: Later on that same page he gives an example of declaring a vector of vectors with -- vector<vector<double>>* p = new vector<vector<double>>(10);    So it is legal to declare such a vector.  My problem is how to initialize and access it correctly, no?

Comment: Your problem is confusion between allocating a single vector with `new`, and allocating ten vectors with `new`. The shown code expects its `new` to allocate ten vectors. It only allocates one, and constructs that vector with ten values. Ten vectors, and one vector with ten values, are two completely different things. After allocating just one vector the code proceeds and attempts to diddle ten vectors, instead of one. Boom.

Comment: Re: `std::ostream os(std::cout.rdbuf());` -- why? You can pass `std::cout` to a function that takes `std::stream&`; there's no need for this redirection. Also, `print_vector` ignores that argument and hard-codes `std::cout`.

Comment: Note, `vector<int>*` is just a pointer to a vector. `m_vec[i]` is the `ith` vector, *not* the ith item of the vector. Per your code, there is only one, so `i>0` cases your code might crash.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use new keyword for vector. Its elements are on the heap/free store always. Look up documentation for vectors and examples on how to initialize them. Also, I'd suggest moving your three using statements outside and above the main function.

Comment: I was able to revise the code per the above about 10 vectors with 1 element vs. 1 vector with 10 elements. But that didn't fix all the problems. I still could not come up with the correct syntax to access individual elements.  So I initialized the vector at the time of declaration with:    vector<int>* m_vec = new vector<int>{ 100, 102, 102, 103, .... };     With this modification passing the pointer to it to the print function worked.  Are there any ideas how to initialize and then access individual elements without initialization in the declaration?

Comment: Message me your code if u can I'll take a look.

Comment: I'd love to Cornel, but can't figure out how.

Comment: You could use an online compiler and share a link for it. For example, https://www.online-cpp.com/

Comment: Here's where I stopped... Code link is to online-cpp.com   https://www.online-cpp.com/gkOKVJfMUo

Comment: I just stumbled across this solution on GitHub.  https://github.com/bewuethr/stroustrup-ppp/blob/main/chapter17/chapter17_drill.cpp  I'm not sure whether this approach to the vector portion of the problem is really right.  One of the first comments says to just simply declare a vector which is on the free  store anyway.. Thoughts please?

Comment: Yeah u dont need to declare new for vectors. By default the vector variable is on the stack, but it's elements are on the heap. No need to use new keyword.